# Upgrading django 1.6 to 1.7. Is there any change in Generic relations for "related_name"?

Tags: python, django, upgrade

I'm trying to upgrade a project from Django 1.6 to 1.7. When I try to run the server I get "TypeError: **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'related_name'":

```
$ ./manage.py runserver --settings=bertondealer.settings.local 0.0.0.0:8000

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/dealer17/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 385, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/dealer17/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 354, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/dealer17/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 21, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/dealer17/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 108, in populate
    app_config.import_models(all_models)
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/dealer17/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 197, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/vagrant_data/projects/companyapps/clientes/models.py", line 3, in <module>
    from distribuidores.models import Empresa as Distribuidor
  File "/vagrant_data/projects/companyapps/distribuidores/models.py", line 50, in <module>
    class Empresa(models.Model):
  File "/vagrant_data/projects/companyapps/distribuidores/models.py", line 88, in Empresa
    eventos = generic.GenericRelation(Evento, related_name='distribuidores_set')
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/dealer17/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/contenttypes/fields.py", line 266, in __init__
    from_fields=[self.object_id_field_name], **kwargs)
  File "/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/dealer17/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 1309, in __init__
    super(ForeignObject, self).__init__(**kwargs)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'related_name'
```

Is this related to any change in Django 1.7?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was no `related_name` for GenericKey.

But you can use [`related_query_name`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#django.contrib.contenttypes.fields.GenericRelation.related_query_name) instead of `related_name` in django 1.7